# zopim chat in PHP Codeigniter Api

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, chat

```
<script>
        $zopim(function() {
            $zopim.livechat.setName({<?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){

                  echo $this->session->userdata('username');

                   } ?>});
            $zopim.livechat.setEmail({<?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){

                  echo $this->session->userdata('email');

                   } ?>});
        });
        </script>
```

I;ve tried in the header but still username and email is not getting on zopim chat

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing some quotes. Try this

```
<script>
    $zopim(function() {
        $zopim.livechat.setName('<?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){

              echo $this->session->userdata('username');

               } ?>');
        $zopim.livechat.setEmail('<?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){

              echo $this->session->userdata('email');

               } ?>');
    });
    </script>
```

You can test it out with this:
http://modernminds.nl/zopim-configuration-customize-api/